# How to trigger ASP.NET application start with command line?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shell, jenkins, command-line

After deploying `ASP.NET` application to servers, I have to send a request by `curl` or browser to trigger it initialize, otherwise, it is keep waiting for the first request to init.

Is there any smarter way to init ASP.NET application from command line?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "init server". Can you elaborate more? Logically speaking, sending request using curl and running the server are two separate things.

Comment: @manouti, sorry I should not say init server, I have done some edit, does it looks clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

You could install `curl` if you need it. Add this to your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get update -q
  - sudo apt-get install curl -y
```